# Consumir API desde C# con RestSharp

Tags: c#, webapi, restsharp

estoy intentado consumir una API post de este modo:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://linkdelAPI/create_or_update.json");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic asmhskashaklsajskajsajsasklsasas==");
            //ACA EL PROBLEMA,  NO SE COMO ENVIAR EL USER:{}, LOS CAMPOS NAME Y EMAIL VAN DENTRO DE USER
            request.AddParameter("name", "Nombre de Prueba", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.AddParameter("email", "correo@correo.com", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Desde el postman mando este tipo de datos, pero en RestSharp C# no se como enviarlos.
  [image: Postman]
Por fa, si alguien sabe el dato me indique como.

Gracias por la ayuda. Tome el ejemplo que me enviaron y lo realice de este modo con RestSharp.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://linkdelapi");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        DatosUser u = new DatosUser();
        u.user = new User
        {
            name = name,
            email = email
        };
        var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic token");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", j, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Yo intentaria hacerlo mediante el ContenString con un post de HttpClient

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: Compartime mas info de como haces con el postman la llamada.

Comment: ahi puse la imagen de como consumo el API, solo mando el link del API, el Header y los datos del body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero creas la clase del servicio y necesitas una clase para crear tu json. Luego llamas al servicio para pasarle la información necesaria, este parsea tu objeto a json, luego crea el `StringContent` con sus parametros y envia todo por `Post`. Para comprobar que todo salio bien, tenes el `if` con dicha comprobación del `status` de la respuesta.

```
public class Service
{
    private HttpClient client;

    public Service()
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
        }
    }
    public async void PostJson(user user)
    {
        var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var content = new StringContent(j, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("uri", content);

        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //respuesta
        }
    }
}

public class user
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

// Desde tu formulario o program.cs o donde lo quieras llamar, lo podes hacer asi.

```
    Service service = new Service();
    user u = new user();

    private async void consumirServicio()
    {
        u.email = "user@test.com";
        u.name = "Prueba";

       await service.PostJson(u);
    }
```

Comment: Ok Ramiro. Realizare de la manera que indicas para hacer pruebas. Realmente de ese modo aún no comprendo a simple vista como es que mandaría los datos. Pero después de la prueba te aviso como me fue. Gracias.

Comment: A ti te pide un json. El metodo recibe tu objeto user, con sus propiedades cargadas de info, ese objeto se serializa a json y se pasa al stringContent, luego ese stringContent al httpclient.Post.

Comment: Sabes, no pude usarlo. Service api = new Service();
            user u = new user();
            u.name = "nombre test";
            u.email = "nombre.test@gmail.com";
            api.PostJson(u); Me muestra un mensaje respecto al async. En realidad no se si es la manera de mandar los datos.

Comment: Te edite la respuesta para que lo puedas llamar. Pero vas a tener que leer sobre metodos asincronicos y Task.